# jQuery multiple classes toggle on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having an issue using jQuery with multiple classes to toggle. 
I have this code:

```
$(function(){
   $(".mobile_btn").on("click", function(){
       $(".main_nav").toggleClass("mobile_active");
   }); 
});
```

what this does is when the user click the **.mobile_btn** the **.main_nav** will toggle with the **.mobile_active** class. Moreover i would like to insert **.container** and **.container_active** and i want them to toggle at the same time as the **.main_nav** with **.mobile_active**. So basically my code should look like this:

```
$(function(){
   $(".mobile_btn").on("click", function(){
       $(".main_nav, .container").toggleClass("mobile_active container_active");
   }); 
});
```

I have tried this but it is not working. Any ideas of how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You need to have 2 different statements

Comment: Your jQuery is good. You don't have `.container` in HTML. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write like this :

```js
$(function(){
   $(".mobile_btn").on("click", function(){
       $(".main_nav").toggleClass("mobile_active");
       $(".container").toggleClass("container_active");
   }); 
});
```

Comment: I have tried that also Sadikali but it still not working

Comment: Can you send me your html?

Comment: <span class="mobile_btn">X</span>
    <!-- Main Nav -->
    <nav class="main_nav">
        <ul class="main_ul">
            <span class="menu_btn"><img src="imgs/menu/line.svg"></span>
            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is use function as argument.

```
$(function() {
  $(".mobile_btn").on("click", function() {
    $(".main_nav, .container").toggleClass(function() {
      return $(this).hasClass('main_nav') ? 'mobile_active' : 'container_active';
    });
  });
});
```

(not suggest, just an option)

Comment: Can you show the code?  @Sadikali Danntreliya 's answer is also correct. May be your "click" event not fired?

Answer (score 1):

Did you test your code? Because it works. See the demo.
You don't have `.container` in your HTML.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function(){
   $(".mobile_btn").on("click", function(){
       $(".main_nav, .container").toggleClass("mobile_active container_active");
   }); 
});
```

```css
.container {outline: 3px dashed green; width: 300px; height: 90px;}
.main_nav {outline: 2px solid blue; width: 100%; height: 30px; }
.mobile_btn { width: 70px; line-height: 1.5; cursor: pointer; }
.main_nav.mobile_active { outline: 3px solid red; background: rgba(255,0,0,.6); color: #CCC; }
.container.container_active{outline: 5px solid #0f0; background: rgba(0,255,0,.3); color: #888; }
.main_nav:after { content:'MOBILE INACTIVE';}
.main_nav.mobile_active:after { content:'MOBILE ACTIVE';}
.container:after { content:'CONTAINER EMPTY';}
.container.container_active:after { content:'CONTAINER FULL';}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="container">
  <nav class="main_nav">
    <button class="mobile_btn">SWITCH</button>
    </nav>
  </section>
```

Comment: No problem. You don't need to change your jQuery, in fact that's the way I'd write it too. It's streamlined.